# Go to a line number in embedded C outside of the function

Tags: c, embedded, goto

Is it possible to call a line number in embedded C that is outside of the function?

Simple goto label commands can't work because I am in the if statement loop: I want to restart the function once the error is greater than 200.

```
void followWall(void)
{

begin:

    int desired = getADC();                                                      //store the first ADC reading as the desired distance from the wall
    int right = 200;                                                             //pre set all variables to be called in the drive function
    int left = 200;                                                              //ints are needed here for bit masking later on to stop overflow
    char rightH = 0;
    char leftH = 0;
    float k = 0.5;                                                               //constant to times the error to fine tune the response
    drive(rightH,right,leftH,left);                                              //drive the robot to the pre set variables

    while( bumpFlag == 0 )                                                       //while the robot has not been bumped or encounted a cliff
    {
        int actual = getADC();                                                   //call a new ADC reading everytime at start of while as the current reading
        rightH = 0;
        leftH = 0;                                                               //set variables back to default to stop constant increase and decrease in variables
        left = 200;
        right = 200;
        char error = abs(actual-desired);                                        //calculate the error by minusing the actual distance to the desired

        if(motorAngle < 180)                                                     //wall on left between 1st and 2nd quadrant
        {
            if(error > 200)
            {
                stop();
                moveStepper(33,0);
                goto begin;
            }
            if (actual > desired)                                                
            {
                 right -=((error)*k);                                            
                 left += ((error)*k);                                            
            }
            else if (actual < desired)                                           
            {
                 left -=((error)*k);                                             
                 right +=((error)*k);                                            
            }
        }
        else if (motorAngle > 180)                                               
        {
            if(error > 200)
            {
                stop();
                moveStepper(33,1);
                goto begin;
            }
            if (actual > desired)                                                
            {
                 left -=((error)*k);                                             
                 right +=((error)*k);                                            
            }
            else if (actual < desired)                                           
            {
                 right -=((error)*k);                                            
                 left +=((error)*k);                                             
            }

        }
     drive(rightH,right,leftH,left);                                                       bumpSensor();                                                               
     setLCDCursor(0x09);
     writeLCDNumber(convert(actual));                                            //constantly write the converted AC value on the LCD
    }
    stop();                                                                      //stop the robot
}
```

Comment: No; the compiler barely knows or cares about line numbers; the `goto` mechanism in standard C is constrained to labels in the current function (not counting `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` — they're not a `goto` but a 'go back to' mechanism); why would you want to do it; and you'd have to jump to code inside some function (code and labels can't exist outside functions), and setting up the call stack across an 'inter-function goto' would be hairy at best and ill-advised and … Generally, it's not a good idea!

Comment: The solution is proper program design, abusing `goto` like this is a very bad idea. However, looking at this code, that's the least of your problems. Why are you using floating point numbers for trivial calculations like these? Why are you using `char` to store integer values? Are you aware of the implementation-defined signedness of char and implicit integer promotions? Why aren't you using stdint.h?  Etc etc. This code needs a complete overhaul.

Comment: Observation: the lines like `right -=((error)*k);` take some reading.  It looks like you are dereferencing a pointer `k` and the coercing the result to type `error`.  However, closer scrutiny shows that `k` is a `char` and `error` is a `float`, so actually it is a simple multiplication on the RHS.  The parentheses are all superfluous: it could be written as `right -= error * k;`, which is simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You should restructure your code to avoid a GOTO. Another loop is needed. Something like this.

```
void followWall(void)
{
  repeat = 0;
  do  // add this loop here
  {
      ...
      ...
      while( bumpFlag == 0 )
      {
         repeat = 0;
         ..
         ..
         if(motorAngle < 180) 
         {
           ..
           if(error > 200)
           {
             ..
             ..
             repeat = 1;
             break;
           }
         }
         else if (motorAngle > 180)   
         {
           ..
           if(error > 200)
           {
             ..
             ..
             repeat = 1;
             break;
           }
         }
       }
  } while (repeat == 1);
}
```